# Fatal error when I enable filter => true in addColumn

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, sales-order, order-grid, fatal-error

I've been able to filter based on custom addColumn to sales_order_create_search grid.

**Custom Added Column**

```
$this->addColumn('seller_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Seller Names'),            
        'index' => 'seller_id',
        'filter'    => true, 
        'sortable'  => true,            
        'renderer'  =>   'adminhtml/sales_order_create_search_grid_renderer_sellername'           
    ));
```

filter => false code is working fine list products with seller names but when try to enable filter => true its generating Fatal error

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: 1'
>   in C:\wamp\www\magetno\app\Mage.php:595 Stack trace:
>   C:\wamp\www\magetno\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495):
>   Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
>
> C:\wamp\www\magetno\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance(true, Array)
>
> C:\wamp\www\magetno\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php(369):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock(true)
>
> C:\wamp\www\magetno\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php(51):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->getFilter()
>
> C:\wamp\www\magetno\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(314):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->setGrid(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid))
>
> C:\wamp\www\magetno\app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Create\Search\Grid.php(156):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->addColumn('seller_id', Array)
>
> C:\wamp\www\magetno\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(624):

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `'filter'    => true,`.
The filter is enabled by default.
And this is not how the filter works.
`filter` is not (only) a boolean value.
If it's set to `false` then no filter is rendered.
Otherwise you need to set it to a block alias.
[Here is an example from the core](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config/Grid.php#L239).

So you cannot use `true` for `filter`

Comment: Good info @Marius.. Got learn from  `no filter is rendered.`